# Statistical test for convergence of an increasing sequence

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

Given a data :
a finite sequence of 10000 terms of increasing real numbers,
each expressed as  decimal form, up to 20th decimal place,

Also suppose that the data was obtained while testing a conjecture in number theory,
so that it is possible to generate beyond 10000-th term.
You can think the data was actually the first 10000 term of the infinite sequence.

**Is there a statistical test** for convergence of the infinite sequence ?

The input : 10000 real numbers of decimal form upto 20 deciaml places
The output : probability 0 to 1 or just likely/unlikey with or without significance.

Comment: There is no such test, period, because (a) it would depend on a probabilistic model and (b) absent such a model, no finite amount of data will ever establish what happens in the limit.